# Why is the following function not càdlàg?

Tags: analysis, stochastic-analysis

I have constructed the following function but I can't see why it is not càdlàg on $[0,1]$:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
1, & x\in\big[0,\tfrac{1}{2}\big),\;\bigg[\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2^{k}},\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{2^{k}}\bigg),\: n=2,4,\ldots\\
0, & x\in\bigg[\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2^{k}},\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{2^{k}}\bigg),\: n=1,3,\dots\end{cases}$$

Comment: Does $\lim_{x \to 1}f(x)$ exist?

Comment: Shouldn't you define $f(1)$?

Comment: yeah, sorry, let $f(1)=1$

Comment: Martin: I see your point!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function is càdlàg on the *half-open* interval $[0,1)$, as you probably verified.

The reason this function can't be extended to a càdlàg function on the *closed* interval $[0,1]$ is that $\lim\limits_{x \to 1} f(x)$ fails to exist: consider e.g. the sequence of midpoints of the intervals appearing in the definition.